# Does Perl support internet?

Tags: perl

I try to write in Perl script for down loading file website. Script must automatically down load at night. Does Perl support internet? I use Perl 5 with CentOS and GEDIT.

Comment: The question is not if Perl supports the internet, but if the internet can support Perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use File::Fetch;
my $url = 'http://domain.tld/path';
my $ff = File::Fetch->new(uri => $url);
my $file = $ff->fetch() or die $ff->error;
print "Check $file\n";
```

Put this in a script and [crontab](/questions/tagged/crontab)...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that Perl is actually the best solution for your problem. You may find that it is easier to simply use a command line tool, like curl. For example, the following command will download a stack overflow banner from it's CDN location, and save the data to a local file called "test.png":

```
curl https://s.zkcdn.net/Advertisers/6a84d696ad6c4679804e4923a617ade4.png > test.png
```

Comment: Yes but I need Perl script to down load file website.